# Blazor's root component is Initialized every time when navigate in auto mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

Blazor's root component is Initialized every time when navigate in auto mode.
If navigate to the same route address, the details page will not be initialized, but the root component will be initialized again.

If set the render mode of the route component to server mode, the root component will not be initialized repeatedly, but the other components will be set to server mode.

Comment: Read - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0 and see this link for a personal commentary on the subject - https://shauncurtis.github.io/Posts/Mongrel-Blazor.html

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Thank you for your comment, this commentary not only answered my questions, but also allowed me to learn about the lifecycle and scope of blazor components